# Ajax "Failed to load resource"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
jQuery('input').live('click',function(e){
    $.getJSON(
        "/json.php",
        function(data){
            the_name = data.name;
        }
    );

});
```

When we press , it should make a json query.

Bit it gives errors.

**In Google Chrome console:**

- Failed to load resource http://site.com/json.php
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

**In Firefox console:**

- GET http://site.com/json.php - is bolded with red color.
- data is null; the_name = data.name;

The strange is when I open http://site.com/json.php, browser gives me a normal json code like:
`{"name":"Mary"}`. It is encoded with php `json_encode();`

**What is the problem?**

Comment: Is your script location on `site.com`? You cannot make cross-domain ajax requests.



http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your json string is not correct:

try

```
$.get("/json.php", function(data) {alert(data)});
```

if you see you data in the alert box try:

```
$.get("/json.php", function(data) {
  var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
  alert(obj.name)
});
```

Comment: If the first test didn't worked that means you have a problem with your script php. The request you make is on the same domain ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `json.php` script didn't set the `Content-Type: application/json` HTTP header?

Comment: it has header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

Comment: @Happy, well then everything seems to be fine. That's very weird. Does `FireBug` show a JSON tab in the response?

Comment: tryed to remove, nothing changes

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov no, there are 3 tabs under the request value http://site.com/json.php, headers are sent, but the answer tab is empty

Comment: @Happy, there seems to be some problem with the server. There must be a Response tab and a JSON tab.

Comment: I'm testing on my local server

Answer (score 0):

Load up [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check the request and response using the Console. Make sure the request is getting sent properly and that the response from the server is properly formatted JSON.

Comment: I've noticed firefox response, json code seems to be valid, checked on the http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: So you can see the proper JSON being returned in the Response tab?

Comment: there is no json tab and no answer from the file request.

Comment: I would try replacing the absolute path, with a relative one. So instead of "/json.php" you could do just "json.php" if the php file is in the same directory as your calling page.